# Wine performance slows when running .exe multiple times

Tags: wine

I'm using Wine to run a surface water model (.exe) with Ubuntu 14.04. I have a shell script that runs the model 1000 times, passing different input directories like so:

```
wine PRZM5.exe "/home/ubuntu/ProjectOutput/177_CAcitrus365_HydC"
wine PRZM5.exe "/home/ubuntu/ProjectOutput/177_CAcitrus366_HydC"
wine PRZM5.exe "/home/ubuntu/ProjectOutput/177_CAcitrus367_HydC"
```

On average, it takes 11 minutes for the first 100 model runs to complete. The next 100 runs take 40 minutes, and the 100 after that take 65 minutes.

What could be causing this major slowdown? Will starting `wineserver -p` before running this help?

Also, are there any configuration settings I could use to increase execution speed, given that I don't need any visual output, just the output files the model generates?

I'm running these scripts on a AWS t1.micro machine-- 0.613 GiB memory with 8 GB hard drive space.

Very new to Linux-- any help appreciated!

Comment: Although not entirely likely, there may be memory leaks occuring when the application is run. I can try to duplicate your results under other situations if you'd like. If I see significant performance impairment on a more powerful machine, it may warrant further investigation or a bug report.

Comment: That would be great, let me know if you need anything from me to duplicate my workflow. Thank you!

Comment: Are you running the program from a terminal, or are you using a terminal emulator in a full desktop environment?

Comment: I have a python script that calls:

    `subprocess.call('bash /home/ubuntu/ProjectOutput/startRuns.sh', shell=True)`

where startRuns.sh is a list of `wine PRZM.exe /path/to/Input/Dir`. Does that answer your question?